# Ruby Lambda expression in Sonar Widget to find a property whose key contains a String

Tags: ruby, lambda, sonarqube

I am writing a plugin for Sonar (now called SonarQube), and for one of the widgets in this plugin I need to return a list of all the properties from the properties table with a key ***containing*** "sonar.score.TitleCup:".  I am a Java programmer, but the widget is written with Ruby Scriptlets and involves Lambda expressions and Closures.  I have spent half of today trying to understand them, but am still having trouble making this widget work.
I started with the following code:

```
properties = Property.find(:all, :conditions => {:prop_key => "sonar.score.TitleCup:BestCoverage"})
```

This worked, and returned the property I was looking for, but I need to be able to find all properties where the prop_key contains "`sonar.score.TitleCup:`".
I tried the following, but it broke the widget (The widget displayed an error message).

```
properties = Property.find(:all, :conditions => {:prop_key.include? "sonar.score.TitleCup:" => true})
```

Anyone familiar with Ruby and Lambda expressions who can help me?  Should I even be using a Lambda expression?

Comment: What is the full type of `Property`? Is that supplied by SonarQube?

Comment: Yes, it is supplied by Sonar, this much I know.  Unfortunately I am not very familiar with Ruby.  What do you mean by "full type"?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sonar development, but it seems to me that if you want to filter the properties, you need to provide a different kind of condition to the `find()` method. The condition `:prop_key=>"..."` implies equality. It could be that the find method supports some other kind of condition, but that'll depend on how it's implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, Sonar is a Rails app, and `Property` is a `ActiveRecord::Base` subclass, the following should do what you want:

```
properties = Property.find(:all, :conditions => ['prop_key LIKE ?','sonar.score.TitleCup:%'])
```

Basically, instead of using the simple `{:key => value}`, you provide a SQL WHERE condition directly (using a placeholder).

You can read about Rails query interface, and specially about conditions at [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions)

Comment: When I used I used `properties = Property.all(:conditions => ['prop_key LIKE ?','sonar.score.TitleCup:%'])` it broke the widget.  However, I used `properties = Property.find(:all, :conditions => ['prop_key LIKE ?','sonar.score.TitleCup:%'])` using the core of your answer, and it worked!  Thank you!

Comment: It must be an old version of Rails, the `.all` shortcut didn’t always exist. I fixed the answer.